# Как отправить запрос с помощью библиотеки LXML.HTML отправить запрос post?

Tags: python-3.x

На официальном сайте написано не понятно.
Есть 2 формы на сайте нужно на 2 форму (ниже) нужно вписать текст name="search" value="" и отправить ее.
http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html#forms

```
<form action="/search/rate" method="post" name="saverate">
                <table cellpadding="0" cellspasing="0" id="form_p">
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="panel">      
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            <input type="text" name="search" value="">
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="hidden" name="token_secure" value="">
                            <input type="hidden" name="uid_secure" value="">
                            <input type="hidden" name="id_project" value="">
                            <input type="hidden" name="code_secure" value="">
                            <input type="hidden" name="mcrate_hash" value="">
                            <span id="buttonrate" class="button_blue" onclick="document.saverate.submit();">Найти</span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
            </form>
```

Comment: Ответ содержится по ссылке, которую вы указали в вопросе. С чем возникли проблемы? Что именно вам там непонятно?

Comment: Проще посмотреть в браузере какие данные заполняются и post запрос с данными формы через requests сделать